# finding current location in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

trying add annotation on current location when ever i want Any number of annotation at the but it work can any help me out 
i try this code

```
 - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude =MKUserLocation.latitude;          //37.786996;// Here we have to change the with current location  
    theCoordinate.longitude = MKUserLocation.longitude;
    return theCoordinate; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Comment: but need to add custom annotation on the currrnt location when ever drop button is click . how can do this droping  the annotation and when the annotation s drop at time the location where the annotation is drop it should store in the sqlite .By which i can see my past journey in future where take photo and all this kind of which intersting .

Comment: You will get the updated coordinates here. Use them for plotting in you map view. You will need to remove the existing annotation and plot again.

Comment: can is not possible to add new annotation  without removing the old annotation  I two button one is photo and another is video button .I need to add annotation for both .and unlimited time on map

Comment: @7KV7 how can i use newLocation object into other class.

Comment: @synthesize the object and use anywhere like any other object.

Comment: @7KV7 But newLocation is into the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

Comment: @7KV7 i try like this but it give error newlocation is not declare     - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{         TNewMap *new ;
 [new locationManager];
 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude =  new.newLocation.coordinate.latitude;                         //37.810000;
    theCoordinate.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude; //-122.477989;
    return theCoordinate; 
 }

Comment: No you shoudnt do like this. Go through some tutorials on Core location using CLLocation Manager.

Comment: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 1):

```
[map setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];
```

map is the object of MKMapView.

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

        if (userLocation_) {
            [userLocation_ release];
        }
        userLocation_ = [newLocation retain];
    }
```

Comment: i am trying to access the other class method in other class  but it give error newlocation is not declare - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate; { TNewMap *new ; [new locationManager]; CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate; theCoordinate.latitude = new.newLocation.coordinate.latitude; //37.810000; theCoordinate.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude; //-122.477989; return theCoordinate; }

Comment: Get your location in appdelegate, then you can use this value through out project.